# Pandas: Filter rows by regex condition

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I've read several questions and answers to this, but I must be doing something wrong. I'd appreciate if someone points at me what it might be.

In my `df` dataframe I have my first column that should always contain six digits, I'm loading the dataframe from Excel, and some smart user thought it would be too funny if adding a disclaimer in the first column.

So I have in the first column something like:

```
['123456', '456789', '147852', 'In compliance with...']
```

So I need to filter only the valid records I'm tryng:

```
pat='\d{6}'
filter = df[0].str.contains(pat, regex=True)
```

This thing returns 'False' for the disclaimer, but `NaN` for the match, so doing a `df[filter]` yields nothing

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `pat='\d{6}'` really must be `pat='^\d{6}$'`, but what do you mean you get `NaN` for the match? Please share a reproducible df example.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do that with the following.

You need to select the rows based on the regex filter.

Note that the current regex that you are using will match anything above 6 digits as well. I changed this to include 6 digits exactly.

```py
df = df[df.columns[0]].str.contains('^[0-9]{6}$', regex=True)
```

Comment: There is an extra ']' at the end. Updated code :```                                                                 
   df = df[df.columns[0]].str.contains('^[0-9]{6}$', regex=True)]```